# C# System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Value removed nested tags

Tags: c#

I have XElement like

```
<text>The temperature is raised <b>75</b> to <b>80</b> Celsius</text>
```

I need to read the value of this XElement and
`element.value` returns
"**The temperature is raised 75 to 80 Celcius**"

could someone please tell how can I get `XElement` value
"**The temperature is raised `<b>`75`</b>` to `<b>`80`</b>` Celsius**"

it seems iterating through elements using

```
var nodes = element.Nodes();
foreach (var node in nodes)
{

}
```

does not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `ToString()` method to get the string representation of an XElement.

```
XElement element = new XElement("text", "The temperature is raised ", new XElement("b", "75"), " to ", new XElement("b", "80"), " Celsius");
string elementString = element.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(elementString);
```

**Updated:** Sorry, now only I understand your problem, try this.

```
string elementValue = "";
foreach (var node in element.Nodes())
{
    elementValue += node.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(elementValue);
```

Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsoG9F

Comment: or: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lot8B8, and then remove `<text>` and `</text>`.  ;-)